# How to call Wordpress First Image Post or else Attached Image or Default

Tags: posts, uploads, images

Can anyone help me develop a wordpress script that [IF] will get first image post and if it doesn't exist it will [ELSE] get first attached (uploaded) image.

**Theoretically:**
[IF exists]

```
<img src="<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>" />
```

[or ELSE]

```
<img src="'. wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID) . '" alt="Main Image" id="mainImage"" />
```

[or ELSE]

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/default.png" />
```

**My current code looks like this (UPDATED.. AGAIN)**

```
<?php  
 $args = array(
 'post_parent' => $post->ID,
 'post_type' => 'attachment',
 'post_mime_type' => 'image',
 'orderby' => 'menu_order',
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'offset' => '0',
 'numberposts' => 1 
 );
 $attachments = get_posts($args);
 $images =& get_children( 'post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent=' . $post->ID );
 if ($attachments) {
 foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
 if(wp_attachment_is_image( $attachment->ID )) {
 echo '<img src="'. wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID) . '" alt="Main Image" id="mainImage"" />'; }}} 
 <!-- else if ( count( $images ) > 0 ) echo get_the_post_thumbnail; } -->
 else {
 echo '<img src="http://hellotokyostore.com/wp-content/themes/hellotokyo/images/default.png" alt="Hello Tokyo" />'; }
?>
```

Comment: Could you explain what this is for dan? Sounds like you're trying to take the post's first image and make it into a thumbnail, but if no image exists, to use a default thumbnail image? If so, there's a better way of going about it :)

Comment: Hey Dunc! 
Basically I need something that will first try to grab the first image on the post (linked image “<img src").
If that doesn't exist, it will try to grab the first image uploaded/attached to the post.
And if that doesn't exist, it will grab a default image (example default.jpg).

Is this possible?! Please help!

Comment: You can see what I'm trying to do here: http://hellotokyostore.com/locations/

Comment: Ah, yes, as I thought - you're after a thumbnail? Have you considered adding a "Featured Image" to your posts? I'll add an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Get The Image][1] plugin by Justin Tadlock, it offer many options and fallbacks for getting images.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Mamaduka! I already tried this and it didn't work.. :(

Comment: What was the problem? Maybe I can help with configuration.

Comment: It is now looking like this: http://hellotokyostore.com/locations/

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer**

Updated the code from dan's comment on this post.

```
<?php 

    $args = array(
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'offset' => '0',
        'numberposts' => 1 
    );

    $images = get_posts($args);

    if ( count( $images ) > 0 ) {

        echo '<img src="'. wp_get_attachment_url($images[0]->ID) . '" alt="Main Image" id="mainImage"" />';

    } else {

       echo '<img src="http://hellotokyostore.com/wp-content/themes/hellotokyo/images/default.png" alt="Hello Tokyo"/>';

    }

?>
```

---

**This information is now out of date but may be useful to another.**

I think what you'd like to do is this:

- Each post has a thumbnail
- If no thumbnail is attached, use a default image

I've adapted code from [this address](http://vanweerd.com/how-to-add-featured-image-thumbnails-to-wordpress-posts-and-pages-the-easy-way/). Have a look at it so you can understand how "Featured Images" work.

The gist is that you'll have a new box on your post page called "Featured image" where you can set a "thumbnail" for each post.

Add the following to your theme's `functions.php`.

```
<?php

if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    /* change these dimensions to suit your website.
       noticed you used 250 * 250 on the page you linked in
       OP comments, so I've used that. you may want to increase
       the size of your individual page's thumbnails */
    add_image_size('index-categories', 250, 250, true);
    add_image_size('page-single', 250, 250, true);
}

function InsertFeaturedImage($content) {

    global $post;

    $original_content = $content;

    $default_thumbnail = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/default_thumbnail.png';
    $default_src = '<img src="' . $default_thumbnail . '" alt="Your caption here" />';

    if ( current_theme_supports( 'post-thumbnails' ) ) {

        if ( ( is_page() ) || ( is_single() ) ) {
            /* if you're viewing a single post
               250 * 250 as designated above */

            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                $content = the_post_thumbnail('page-single');
            } else {
                $content = $default_src;
            }

            $content .= $original_content;
        } else {
            /* if you're viewing a list of posts, use this size of thumbnail
               250 * 250 as designated above */

            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {   
                $content = the_post_thumbnail('index-categories');
            } else {
                $content = $default_src;
            }

            $content .= $original_content;
        }

    }

    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'InsertFeaturedImage' );

?>
```

Please don't hesitate to ask if any part of this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hey Dunc! Thanks for this script. But I'm looking for something that won't require to use "Feature Image". Because alot of times, I just take a picture using Instagram (via iphone) and it automatically posts it to Wordpress! This allows me to quickly upload and update the website without having to login to the site all the time :)

Comment: Try my updated answer.

Comment: Am I doing something completely wrong? Placed the script in function.php . Then put <?php echo displayThumbFromImages() ?> and now getting an error.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use the function itself dan; the filter `add_filter ('the_content', 'displayThumbFromImages');` should do the trick (put the code in `functions.php`). I've updated my code a little, try refreshing.

Comment: Hmm.. now its doing something really different. It's placing the image in content area and repeating itself on other posts. Also where the picture needs to go is now empty. Please see the site for reference http://hellotokyostore.com/locations/

Comment: Updated again. Use new code and `<?php echo displayThumbFromImages(); ?>` in your `index.php` or wherever you're listing posts (categories, etc).

Comment: And needed to add `global $post` (as per amendment) but that appears to be working for me.

Comment: Just to give you heads up, my current code looks like this

Comment: <?php  
    $args = array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'offset' => '0',
    'numberposts' => 1 
    );
    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
    if(wp_attachment_is_image( $attachment->ID )) {
    echo '<a href="'. wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID) . '" class="thumbnail">'. wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID) .'</a>';
    break; }
    } }
    ?>

Comment: I presume you're using a `WP_Query` then? If so, run my function after the query. Run it exactly where you want the image to display, i.e. between `<div class="thumbnail">` or wherever you're putting it.

Comment: I've put my code in question. Do you mind somehow adding an else script to get the first image?

Comment: Done. See if that works for you?

Comment: I'm getting an error on the following line: 
echo '<a href="'. wp_get_attachment_url($images[0]) . '" class="thumbnail">'. wp_get_attachment_image($images[0], 'thumbnail', false); .'</a>';

Comment: Is there anyway you can modify my script at the very top question and somehow add a first image "else" statement? Im such a newb at this..

Comment: OK Dan, try now?

Comment: Dunc!! I think we are almost there!! Please take a look at my code one more time. The part <!-- else if ( count( $images ) > 0 ) echo get_the_post_thumbnail; } --> needs to be replaced with something that will pull the first image on post!

Comment: Try now Dan? I've just added `[0]` to the end of the `$images` array to determine the first entry.

Comment: I would recommend that you try copying my entire code by the way - you've got a couple of redundant functions/arrays in yours now (presuming you're using the code that you've updated your OP with). Feel free to paste me exact errors if my exact code doesn't work.

Comment: I have tried your code. Both are doing the same thing.  The first post image (Red box) isn't appearing where the default (blue box) is.

Comment: Have you used the most recent code where I've added the `[0]`?

Comment: yup.. still no love :(

Comment: Can you give me a link where it isn't working? I could also do with some additional "context" code, i.e. where your code is appearing on the page.

Comment: http://hellotokyostore.com/orange/

Comment: It looks like you're using my code outside the loop dan. Can you please give me the "surrounding" code, so that I can see where the loop is and where this code is being positioned?

Comment: since the code is too long, i've uploaded into a text file. http://hellotokyostore.com/docs/program.txt

Comment: Try replacing your entire code with the code from this URL: http://pastebin.com/rLCqnPKF

Comment: It's making everything into red box now.

Comment: Try this: http://pastebin.com/rW5wxVrw then can you give me a URL once it's in place so I can see where it's going wrong?

Comment: http://hellotokyostore.com/locations/

I'm guessing it might be in my initial coding for the thumbnail boxes. Because if i click the thumbnail in bottom box, it changes the large image in the top box. #FAIL

Comment: Try removing the additional " at the end of line 46 on my last Pastebin.

Comment: Now all the images disappeared. Oh well I guess this might not really have any run around it. Thanks for trying to help me out. Not sure where you're at, but its almost 7 in the morning and got to get few hours of sleep. Thanks for everything. I really mean it!

Comment: **Please take this discussion to [a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)!** Comments are not intended for ongoing conversation.